# How to output the parent and child category in both parent / child category template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

*I try to show the parent and child category in both parent / child-category template ( woocommerce ).
I used this code bellow and it just showing the child category in parent category.*

Update code:

```
<?php
            $counter = 0;
            $term = get_queried_object();

            $children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
                'parent'    => $term->term_id,
                'hide_empty' => false
            ) );

            $categories = [ $term ];

            // If $children is an array just merge the "current" (parent) category with the children
            if ( is_array( $children ) ) {
                $categories = array_merge( $categories, $children );
            }


            foreach( $categories as $subcat ) {
                    echo '<ul><li><a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">' . $subcat->name . '</a></li></ul>';
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are querying all the "children", in the case you are trying to create an array with all the data you already have it you only need to construct it.

```
<?php
            $counter = 0;
            $term = get_queried_object();

            $children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
                'parent'    => $term->term_id,
                'hide_empty' => false
            ) );

            $categories = [ $term ];

            // If $children is an array just merge the "current" (parent) category with the children
            if ( is_array( $children ) ) {
                $categories = array_merge( $categories, $children );
            }


            foreach( $categories as $subcat ) {
                    echo '<ul><li><a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">' . $subcat->name . '</a></li></ul>';
            }
        ?>
```

As you can see on the example above there's a small portion of code added to merge both arrays into a single array instead.

Comment: Thanks, so how to display all the list child category and parent category in child category template ? for example:
-parent category
   -- child category 01
   -- child category 02
   -- child category n
the template of --child category will include -parent category and also include other child category.